# Prove That $\sum\sum\binom{k-m-mi}{i}=\sum\binom{n+1-mj}{j}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

**Question**

This is inspired by a question regarding the same identity for special case $m=1$ : [$\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k-1-i}{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1-j}{j}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4247959/751970) . I want to prove that the following expression is true for non negative integers $m$:

$$
\sum_{k=m}^{n}{\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor}{\binom{k-m-mi}{i}}}=\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{m+1}\right\rfloor}{\binom{n+1-mj}{j}}
$$

**My Solution**

*Left Hand Side*

If we have $k+1$ indistinguishable candies and distribute it to $i+1$ distinguishable boxes where each box contain at least $m+1$ candies, the number of possible distribution is given by the binomial coefficient on the left side using Stars and Bars:

$$
\binom{(k+1)-m(i+1)-1}{(i+1)-1}=\binom{k-m-mi}{i}
$$

The left hand side then gives the number of all possible distribution of $m+1,m+2,…,n+1$ candies to all possible number of boxes:

$$
\sum_{k=m}^{n}{\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor}{\binom{k-m-mi}{i}}}
$$

*Right Hand Side*

For each candies distribution, add another box filled with at least $m+1$ candies so that the total number of candies being distributed is always $n+m+2$. Notice that we get all possible distribution of $n+m+2$ indistinguishable candies to all possible number of boxes where each box contains at least $m+1$ candies, except the distribution in which all $n+m+2$ candies are in one box. The right hand side gives the number of these possible distribution:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{m+1}\right\rfloor}{\binom{n+1-mj}{j}}
$$

*Conclusion*

Since both left and right hand sides are used to count the same objects they must be equal.

**Seeking Help**

Need your help to see if my solution is correct and I will also appreciate alternatives and discussions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice binomial identity
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=m}^n\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{k-m-mj}{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n+1-mj}{j}\qquad\qquad 0\leq m\leq n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is correct. Here is an algebraic proof.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=m}^n\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{k-m-mj}{j}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{k-mj}{j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\sum_{k=j(m+1)}^{n-m}\binom{k-mj}{j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\sum_{k=j}^{n-m-jm}\binom{k}{j}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-m-jm+1}{j+1}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-m}{m+1}\right\rfloor+1}\binom{n-jm+1}{j}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{m+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-jm+1}{j}}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we shift the index of the outer sum to start with $k=0$.
- In (3) we exchange the sums. We observe considering the upper index of the binomial coefficient $\binom{k-mj}{j}$:
  \begin{align*}
  k-mj&\geq j\\
  mj+j&\geq k\\
  k&\geq j(m+1)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $k=j$.
- In (5) we apply the *[hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)*.
- In (6) we shift the index to start with $j=1$.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the answer +1

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja: You're welcome! :-)